# Synchronizing Audio Playback with UI in Node.js and Electron App

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm developing an app using Node.js and Electron aimed at learning English vocabulary through an API. However, I'm facing challenges in implementing the desired functionality.

The general idea is as follows: I retrieve 10 words from the API and display them automatically in the window, one by one, at user-defined intervals (in this example, every 5 seconds). Each word is sent to the AWS Polly service to obtain its English pronunciation, which is then played back. Afterward, there's a 3-second wait before playing an example of the word in English, followed by waiting for the specified interval to move on to the next word.

Additionally, I've included a button to repeat the currently displayed word along with its example. However, I'm struggling to implement this functionality correctly. When I click the button, the next word starts playing, even though the previous one is still displayed on the screen, or the word on the screen changes but the previous one continues playing.

I'd appreciate guidance on how to resolve this issue to ensure that word and example playback syncs properly with the user interface.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Words in English</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="word"></div>
    <div id="error"></div>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="number" id="intervalInput" min="1" max="999" value="1" placeholder="Intervalo">
      <select id="voiceSelect">
        <option value="Matthew">Matthew</option>
        <option value="Joanna">Joanna</option>
      </select>
      <button id="repeatButton">repeat</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="renderer.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

renderer.js

```
const  {speak,updateVoiceConfig,pauseAudio,stopAudio,resumeAudio }  = require('./polly/pollyServices.js');

let currentIndex = 0;
let intervalId;
let data;
let time =5;

async function fetchData() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3005/randomwords', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
    
    data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
    return null;
  }
}


function checkFetchApiStatus() {
  if (!data) {
    document.getElementById('error').innerText = 'No se pudieron obtener los datos de la API.';
    return;
  }
}

async function loadDataIfNeeded() {
  if (currentIndex === 0 || !data || data.length === 0) {
    data = await fetchData();
  }
}

function displayWord() {
  const word = data[currentIndex];
  const wordElement = document.getElementById('word');
  let content = "";
  for (const key in word) {
    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(word, key) && key !== "wordID") {
      content += `${word[key]}\n`;
    }
  }
  wordElement.innerText = content.trim();
}

let isPlaying = false;

async function playWord(text) {
  if (isPlaying) {
    stopAudio();
  }
  isPlaying = true;
  await speak(text);
  isPlaying = false;
}



async function nextWord() {
  
  await loadDataIfNeeded();
  checkFetchApiStatus();
  await displayWord();

  await playWord(data[currentIndex].english);
  
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
  await playWord(data[currentIndex].example_sentence);
  currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % data.length;

 
  intervalId = setTimeout(nextWord, time * 1000);
  
}

function setupListeners() {
  const intervalInput = document.getElementById('intervalInput');
  const voiceSelect = document.getElementById('voiceSelect');

  intervalInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
    time = intervalInput.value;
  });

  voiceSelect.addEventListener('change', () => {
    const selectedVoice = voiceSelect.value;
    updateVoiceConfig(selectedVoice);
  });

  
  const listenButton = document.getElementById('repeatButton');
  listenButton.addEventListener('click', async function () {
  });
}



window.onload = function() {
  setupListeners();
  nextWord(); 
};
```

pollyServices.js

```
const AWS = require('./pollyConfig.js');
const { Howl } = require('howler');
const polly = new AWS.Polly();

let voiceId = 'Matthew'; // Voz predeterminada

function updateVoiceConfig(newVoiceId) {
    voiceId = newVoiceId;
}

// Variable global para manejar la instancia actual del sonido
let sound;
async function speak(text) {
    try {
      const params = {
        Text: text,
        OutputFormat: 'mp3',
        SampleRate: '24000',
        VoiceId: voiceId,
        TextType: 'ssml',
      };
      const ssml = `<speak><prosody rate="slow">${text}</prosody><break time="2s"/></speak>`;
      params.Text = ssml;
      const resultado = await polly.synthesizeSpeech(params).promise();
  
      if (resultado.AudioStream instanceof Buffer) {
        // Detiene la reproducción actual si hay una
        if (sound) {
          sound.stop();
        }
  
        // Crea una nueva instancia de Howl para el nuevo audio
        sound = new Howl({
          src: ['data:audio/mpeg;base64,' + resultado.AudioStream.toString('base64')],
          format: ['mp3'],
          onplay: () => {
            console.log('Audio is playing');
          },
          onend: () => {
            console.log('Audio has finished playing');
          }
        });
  
        sound.play();
      } else {
        console.error('Error al sintetizar el habla.');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error al convertir texto a voz:', error);
    }
  }
  
  function pauseAudio() {
    if (sound && sound.playing()) {
      sound.pause();
    }
  }
  
  function stopAudio() {
    if (sound) {
      sound.stop();
    }
  }
  
  function resumeAudio() {
    if (sound && !sound.playing()) {
      sound.play();
    }
  }
  

  module.exports = {speak,updateVoiceConfig,pauseAudio,stopAudio,resumeAudio} ;
```

Attempted Solution:
Implemented a button in the Electron app interface to repeat the currently displayed word along with its example.

Expected Outcome:
Upon clicking the button, the app should repeat the current word and its example, followed by waiting for the specified interval before automatically moving on to the next word. The audio playback and UI should remain synchronized, ensuring that the correct word and example are displayed and played.

Actual Result:
Upon clicking the button, the next word starts playing immediately, even though the previous one is still displayed on the screen. Alternatively, the word displayed on the screen changes, but the audio playback continues with the previous word. This asynchronous behavior disrupts the intended flow of the app and leads to confusion for the user.

It seems that despite the implementation of the button to repeat the word, there's a synchronization issue between the audio playback and the UI display, causing the app's behavior to deviate from the expected outcome.

Comment: _"When I click the button, the next word starts playing, even though the previous one is still displayed on the screen"_ Have you tried including a check to make sure the current word is not being played as sound or displayed on screen in `nextWord`, so that you are not restarting the routine even though there is an ongoing routine?

Comment: I replied below

Comment: You should probably just post that as a comment unless your answer actually answers your question. Looking at your code, you might need a way to halt and resume, and change the values in your non-terminating asynchronous function that refers to itself.

Comment: I attempted a flag-based approach to halt the recursive function and restart it from a button press to replay the current word. However, synchronization issues arose; depending on the timing of the button click, the index incremented, leading to desynchronization. Meanwhile, the recursive function persisted while the button function executed. I'm uncertain why this occurs. The code snippet provided was a simplified example of my current implementation without button functionality. I've exhausted other options and am unsure what else to try.

Comment: I would wait to call `nextWord()` until after the current word is displayed and rendered to speakers. Then call `nextWord()`. Include a way to clear the timeout, remove event listsners and reset event listeners.